# How to get Facebook share count for all links shared using a given application via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a list of statistics/analytics for all the links shared using a server-side Facebook application via the Facebook API?

I have a list of links that can be shared to Facebook using the appId defined in my server app. In order to refresh the share count of those items, I'm currently calling:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{MY_URL}
```

whenever I want to update those values.

Obviously, this solution is not very scalable, because the number of items constantly grows so I can't call the method on all the URLs in sequence. Alternatively, this information can be fetched every time it needs to be visualized to the users. However, this can mean that the same request will be made to Facebook API in quick succession even though the chances of anything changing are small.

Ideally, I would like to get a list of all the links/items shared using my application with the share count for each of them. This way I can do a nightly update of all the values without going one by one.

I'm using the

```
me/links
```

API method to share the links to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Analytics of a post, shared by a page can be accessed by the [Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights)

Below id the Graph API call to access the count of clicks sent to your domain by a certain post.

```
/v2.4/<object-id>/insights/domain_feed_clicks?period=lifetime
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please refer to the permalink mentioned above and find the metric which best suits your need.

Comment: I looked through the Insights API but I couldn't find what I need. Let's say my application shares three links:

https://myapp.com/link1
https://myapp.com/link2
https://myapp.com/link3

and several people like those links on FB. 

I now want to get a list from FB, using ONLY my app_id to get a list of all those links and a number of likes:

    /v2.4/<app-id>/insights/url-likes

    {
    "https://myapp.com/link1" : 12,
    "https://myapp.com/link2" : 13,
    "https://myapp.com/link3" : 0
    }

I don't think such a method exists

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get a list of all the links/items shared using my application

The API does not provide that kind of list.

---

To reduce the number of API requests you have to make, you can request the data for several URLs in one go though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#multirequests

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com/foo,http://example.com/bar,…
```

(You should properly URL-encode any URLs you use a parameter values here of course.)

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. The problem with multi requests is that the number of links might go into thousands or more, which also doesn't make it very useful. Loading all the links from the database, forming a huge request and expecting a huge response is also not the perfect solution. 

It seems that the front-end triggered approach is the best one in this case.

Comment: When doing this on the frontend, you might run into API request limits quite quickly – unless you make the user of your site login to Facebook, so that you can use their user access token. I’d probably rather go with a server-side solution, that requests data for a couple of URLs every five minutes or so, and caches the results.

Comment: I'm not using any tokens for this method since it doesn't require one. Does Facebook block requests based on IPs? Also, you might have misunderstood me. Our frontend is calling our backend to call FB API and update the values. We keep the values in the database. However, there is no caching right now so every time a user opens the specific page, a call js made to FB through our server. We can limit that to, say, once every hour, which is a good idead and a good place to start optimizing.

Comment: From API v2.0 on, every API call (expect for a user’s profile picture) requires an access token. So while making this call without specifying an API version might still work for now, it might stop doing so at any moment. Compare https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/?ids=http://example.com/foo (what you are implicitly using right now), to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?ids=http://example.com/foo

Comment: And if you are taking values from your own database, isn’t that a form of caching already? Why do you make a request to FB every time the user visits your page, if you have those values in your database already …?

Comment: I'm doing this to trigger a read of the latest values. Say a link has been shared. User 1 at time t1 goes to my page and triggers the read of likes/shares count, which results in the value n. It is stores in the database. Then, at time t2, another users visit the website and the read is triggered again to get the new value of likes/shares count = m. In the meantime the values are not refreshed but can be used to sort the content by the number of FB interactions.